# Expression<> & Func<> clarification in entity framework dot net core 2

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

so i am currently in the process of migrating our code base from EF 6 to EF core 2.0 and i am just running into a few problems with Expressions.

So we have some common filters that we have abstracted out to an Expression.

```
    public static Expression<Func<AutotaskContractServiceUnit, bool>> ThisMonth()
    {
        var startDate = Clock.Now.Start();
        var endDate = Clock.Now.End();

        return csu => csu.StartDate.Date >= startDate.Date && csu.EndDate.Date <= endDate.Date;
    }
```

And this is consumed as follows

```
        return from vc in ContractRepository.GetAll()
               let isAssigned = vc.AssetId != null
               join v in _veeamRepository.GetAll() on vc.AssetId equals v.Id into veeams
               from v in veeams.DefaultIfEmpty()
               join ac in AutotaskContractRepository.GetAll() on vc.ContractId equals ac.Id
               join ats in AutotaskServiceRepository.GetAll() on vc.ServiceId equals ats.Id
               let billed = ac.ContractServiceUnits // navigation property
               .AsQueryable()
                   .Where(AutotaskContractServiceUnitFilters.ThisMonth())
                   .Where(csu => csu.ServiceID == vc.ServiceId)
                   .OrderByDescending(csu => csu.Id)
                   .FirstOrDefault()
               select new VeeamBillingModel
               {
// property selection 
               };
```

The actual issue is with this part of the query

```
           let billed = ac.ContractServiceUnits
           .AsQueryable()
               .Where(AutotaskContractServiceUnitFilters.ThisMonth())
               .Where(csu => csu.ServiceID == vc.ServiceId)
               .OrderByDescending(csu => csu.Id)
               .FirstOrDefault()
```

As i get this exception

> Could not parse expression '<>h__TransparentIdentifier4.<>h__TransparentIdentifier3.ac.ContractServiceUnits.AsQueryable()': This overload of the method 'System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable' is currently not supported.

So my question is, how can you achieve the same result in EF Core?

Things i've tried

1. Remove the AsQueryable(). The problem with this is that the compiler then complains that it cannot convert an Expression<> to Func<> 
   `Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<Portal.Autotask.ContractServiceUnit.Entities.AutotaskContractServiceUnit, bool>>' to 'System.Func<Portal.Autotask.ContractServiceUnit.Entities.AutotaskContractServiceUnit, bool>'`
2. Change the Expression<> to a Func<> which compiles fine, but as soon as it tries to execute the query it throws an exception because its not an Expression<>.
3. I've also tried LinqKit (briefly) but couldn't get it working. I think because its from a joined table the .AsExpandable() doesn't work correctly.

The only way i have managed to get this working is to manually put the expression in the .Where clause.

```
           let billed = ac.ContractServiceUnits
               .Where(x => x.StartDate.Date >= start.Date && x.EndDate <= end.Date)
               .Where(csu => csu.ServiceID == vc.ServiceId)
               .OrderByDescending(csu => csu.Id)
               .FirstOrDefault()
```

But this is not a good solution really as we have other expressions where the query logic could change and manually updating all the queries is too time consuming.

If anyone can shed a bit of light on this, that would be ace,
Cheers!

Comment: Sad to say, it will not be possible to write it in EF Core. EF uses Remotion.Linq to parse expression tree before processing query. But as of now Remotion.Linq does not support `AsQueryable` overload. Tracking issue https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/6132